# how to automatically retrieve selected value

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

is there a way to automatically retrieve selected value from dropdown or radio to form below?
example in the image below, if i select radio button "randy", then the value "randy" automatically fill in the form Nama below

[image]

```
$header1 = array('Name'); // Prepare table header
$query = db_select("homo", "r"); // Select table  
$query->fields("r", array("nama")); // Select fields    
$result = $query->execute(); // Execute query 
$rows = array();
while($data = $result->fetchObject()){ // Looping for filling the table rows  
$rows[] = array( // Fill the table rows
  $data->nama,
  );
}
$form['table'] = array (
 '#type' => 'tableselect',
 '#header' => $header1,
 '#options' => $rows,
 '#multiple' => FALSE,  
);
$form['f1'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Detail Anggota'),
 '#type' => 'fieldset',    
);
$form['f1']['namaa'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Nama'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',    
 '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do this for you. Something like the code below would accomplish your task easily.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('checkbox_type');
         for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
             if(checkbox[i].checked == true) {
                  $('input[name=namaa]').val($(checkbox[i]).text());
             }
         }
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: where do i put js script? below the module, or out module file?

Comment: You have to write this javascript code inside the template file of your module.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add the JS from your HOOK_form_alter like so:

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodulename') . '/js/myjsname.js';
```